# Python Speedtest or speedtest_cli

Tags: python

when I started the program . the function after the expression does not see it directly becomes as if Speedtest() does not exist

```py
from speedtest import Speedtest

internet = Speedtest()

download_speed = internet.download()
upload_speed = internet.upload() 

print("Download \t:", download_speed)
print("Upload   \t:", upload_speed)
```

console output:

```bash
File "c:\xxx\xxx\Desktop\yazilim\netspeed\be3.py", line 1, in <module>
    from speedtest import Speedtest
ImportError: cannot import name 'Speedtest' from 'speedtest' (C:\xxx\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\speedtest\__init__.py)
```

```
Download: 38.06 Mbit/s
Upload: 10.80 Mbit/s
```

Comment: Did you install the `speedtest` package? You need to install with this command: `pip install speedtest-cli`